# asp.net image button sends null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, imagebutton

hi im trying to pass a value to the model using an image button but it is saying that ive just sending nothing can anyone help.

ive got it working with a normal input button

```
<input type="submit" name="Vote" value="6" />
```

but not with images.

```
<input type="image" src="..urlpath" name="Vote" value="6"/>
<button type="submit" name="Vote" value="6"> 6 <img src="...urlpath" /></button>
```

if you can help me that would be great thanks

controller

```
        public ActionResult PlanVote()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PlanVote(int vote)
    {
        PlanModel myModel = PlanModel.Instance;
        myModel.Vote(vote);

        if (PlanModel.Instance.currentstate == PlanState.displaying)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Plan");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Waiting", "Plan");
        }
     }
```

model

```
    public void Vote(int Votes)
    {


        ivote.Add(Votes);

        if (countVotes >= iCount)
        {
            currentstate = PlanState.displaying;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Show your `HttpPost` controller actionresult

Answer (score 0):

Read the HTML [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1):

> **image**
>
> Creates a graphical submit button. The value of the src
>   attribute specifies the URI of the image that will decorate the
>   button. For accessibility reasons, authors should provide alternate
>   text for the image via the alt attribute. When a pointing device is
>   used to click on the image, the form is submitted and the click
>   coordinates passed to the server. The x value is measured in pixels
>   from the left of the image, and the y value in pixels from the top of
>   the image. The submitted data includes name.x=x-value and
>   name.y=y-value where "name" is the value of the name attribute, and
>   x-value and y-value are the x and y coordinate values, respectively.
>
> If the server takes different actions depending on the location
>   clicked, users of non-graphical browsers will be disadvantaged. For
>   this reason, authors should consider alternate approaches:
>
> Use multiple submit buttons (each with its own image) in place of a
>   single graphical submit button. Authors may use style sheets to
>   control the positioning of these buttons. Use a client-side image map
>   together with scripting.

Comment: Interesting! I've got *value* with chrome (three param, name.x, name.y and name) but *firefox* returns two params (x & y).